# Updating records via api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, crud

Ive just started upgrading an old .net framework platform to .net Core 5 using Razor Pages

The first issue i ran into is on updating records.

We have a frontend and a backend form to edit users. On frontend only few fields are visible and on backend we have more fields

The model could look like this

```
public class User
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int UserType {get;set;}
    public DateTime TStamp {get;set;}
}
```

On frontend the user can update the name, and i don't want to expose the value of UserType(or TStamp) using a hidden field.

But this means that the Usertype and TStamp always are reset

I have read the the best way is to send the model to the server and then update(and validate) the record serverside like :

```
Model recordToUpdate = GetRecordFromDB(id)
recordToUpdate.Name = postedRecord.Name;
UpdateRecord(recordToUpdate);
return recordToUpdate
```

Is there anyway else to accomplish update only few fields ?

08-02-2021 11:57
I have found this script which iterates through a model and a viewmodel and then transfer data.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5163606/Generic-MVVM-Data-Exchange-between-Model-and-ViewM

```
public enum MVVMDirection { FROM, TO };

/// <summary>
/// ViewModel base class
/// </summary>
public class VMBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Move the data from the model to the viewmodel, using reflection. 
    /// Property names in both objects MUST be the same (both name and type)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">The model's type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="model">The model object the data will be moved from</param>
    public void UpdateFromModel<TModel>(TModel model)
    {
        this.Update<TModel>(model, MVVMDirection.FROM);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Move the data from the viewmodel to the model, using reflection. 
    /// Property names in both objects MUST be the same (both name and type)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">The model's type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="model">The model object the data will be moved from</param>
    public void UpdateToModel<TModel>(TModel model)
    {
        this.Update<TModel>(model, MVVMDirection.TO);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update to or from the model based on the specified direction. Property names in both 
    /// objects MUST be the same (both name and type), but properties used just for the view 
    /// model aren't affected/used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">The model's type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="model">The model object the data will be moved to/from</param>
    /// <param name="direction">The direction in which the update will be performed</param>
    public void Update<TModel>(TModel model, MVVMDirection direction)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] mProperties = model.GetType().GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] vmProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo mProperty in mProperties)
        {
            PropertyInfo vmProperty = this.GetType().GetProperty(mProperty.Name);
            if (vmProperty != null)
            {
                if (vmProperty.PropertyType.Equals(mProperty.PropertyType))
                {
                    if (direction == MVVMDirection.FROM)
                    {
                        vmProperty.SetValue(this, mProperty.GetValue(model));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vmProperty.SetValue(model, mProperty.GetValue(this));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `TStamp` is a concurrency field, you should pass it to the user and back to ensure no one else has changed the db record. Usually you would define a view model with the fields the view is allowed to change. Perhaps using AutoMapper to copy to / from the DB record.

Comment: it depends on your orm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF Core, you can tell it which properties have to be updated in this way:

```
var user = new User{ ID = id, Name = postedRecord.Name};
_dbContext.Employee.Attach(user);
_dbContext.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```